# Explicit free list (dynamic memory allocation)

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I need some help with my assignment. My job is to create/implement malloc/free functions in C using “Explicit free list among only the free blocks” technique. I have already studied a lot of materials, but I am still stuck at some point and I do not understand some details. So my job is to create 4 functions – initialize(), allocate() ,free() and check(). I can use only one global variable `void *memory` – this is the block  in which I can allocate my memory using alloc().

So I wanted to implement this using doubly linked-list and I created a structure:

```
typedef struct memoryBlock{
    struct memoryBlock *prev,*next;
}memoryBlock;
```

And the structure for the header:

```
typedef struct header{
int size;
}header;
```

I was advised in my class to create a separate structure for a free memory block and another separate structure for an allocated block. My first idea was to distinguish the free/allocated blocks using one bit of the block size in header – set it to 1 if the block is allocated and 0 if it is free. ( I saw this technique used in implicit lists). So my question is: do I need to create a `freeBlock` and `allocatedBlock` structure for an explicit list or can I just use the one bit of the size?

The second question is: do I need a separate structure for the header/footer of the block? Or can I just write the size of the block in the header/footer as `*(int *)ptr = size;` ? I tried to use this in the initialize() function:

```
void initialize(void *ptr, int size){
memory = ptr;
*(int *)memory = size; //header
*((int *)memory + size) = size; //footer
}
```

Is this  correct, please?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You can only use one bit of `size` if it is unused otherwise. If you choose bit 0 it will only work when only even numbers of memory words are allocated. I'd rather use two lists or add another element to the struct as a flag. The code will be so must clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to create a freeBlock and allocatedBlock structure for an explicit list[…]?

This sound to me like a very good idea. Just don't misunderstand the advice: You don't need two different structure **definitions** but two different lists. You can realize this with two pointers, one for free blocks and one for allocated blocks.

> […] can I just use the one bit of the size?

You can only use one bit of size if it is unused otherwise. If you choose bit 0 it will only work when only even numbers of memory words are allocated.

> do I need a separate structure for the header/footer of the block?

That depends on your design and algorithm. Are you bound to create a header and a footer?

> Or can I just write the size of the block in the header/footer as `*(int *)ptr = size;`?

You can do this. But I would assign the given pointer to a (temporary) pointer to the right struct and then assign values right in their places.

```
void initialize(void *ptr, int size) {
    memory = ptr;
    header* h = memory;
    h->size = size;
}
```

Additional observation: Instead of

```
typedef struct memoryBlock{
    struct memoryBlock *prev,*next;
}memoryBlock;
```

better get used to this, it will save you a lot of pulled-out hair:

```
typedef struct memoryBlock {
    struct memoryBlock *prev;
    struct memoryBlock *next;
} memoryBlock;
```

*Note: Due to the (seemingly) complexity of pointer, please raise the warning level of you compiler to the maximum. Read all warnings and eliminate their reasons.*

Comment: Hello, I am not sure whether I can use two separate lists - I am only allowed to use one global variable - `void *memory` and this is the block of memory where all the pointers from my function allocate() will be allocated. And speaking of the one bit that represents free/allocated block, can I use a bit field in the header structure instead? Because I think I will work with both even and odd numbers of memory words.

Comment: You can place two pointers at the beginning of the block pointed to by `memory`. Instead of a bit field use a boolean (include `stdbool.h`!), it will use the same space most probably but is the right data type..

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can I have one more question - is there any other way I can mark the block as allocated/free without using any extra memory? I wanted to use the one bit of the size only to save memory, but this way I can only use even sized blocks of memory as you said earlier... Can I for example multiply the size of the block with -1 and I will know that if there is a header/footer with negative size, it is already allocated block? Thanks.

Comment: If you have two lists you don't need to mark a block. Your function have to unlink the block from one list and link it into the other list if it is allocated or freed. But be aware that both function are not trivial. `allocate()` needs to split a free block into two blocks if the requested size is smaller than the to-be-used free block. `free()` should join a returned block if it is adjacent to another free block.